# MATLAB cant find class from Simulink Check

Tags: matlab, simulink

MATLAB cannot find the class of a toolbox - What do I do?

Basically I want to use the [Width](https://mathworks.com/help/slcheck/ref/slmetric.dashboard.widget.getwidths.html) class of the toolbox library slmetric, but MATLAB cannot find the library. How do I properly troubleshoot that problem?

```
>> misraWidget.setWidths(slmetric.dashboard.Width.Medium);
Undefined variable "slmetric" or class "slmetric.dashboard.Width.Medium".
```

Or

```
>> getWidths(misraWidget)
Error using slmetric.dashboard.CustomWidget/getWidths
The class 'slmetric.dashboard.Width' contains a parse error, cannot be found on MATLAB's
search path, or is shadowed by another file with the same name.
```

I tried to use "which" to understand better whats going on and compare the results for Group, which implies that slmetric.* is present and the results for Width:

```
>> which slmetric.dashboard.Group
slmetric.dashboard.Group is a built-in method  % slmetric.dashboard.Group constructor
>> which slmetric.dashboard.Width
'slmetric.dashboard.Width' not found.
>> which slmetric.dashboard.Width.Medium
'slmetric.dashboard.Width.Medium' not found.
```

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial on how to customize your metrics dashboard](https://mathworks.com/help/slcheck/ug/customize-dashboard-layout-functionality.html) for the toolbox Simulink Check. I use the [Simulink Bounce Demo](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulation-of-a-bouncing-ball.html) as an example. I would appreciate it, if someone can explain to me how to generally solve such a problem in MATLAB. The "build/linking" in MATLAB is hidden away so I don't really understand how to tackle these kinds of things. The best thing I found via searching was the "which" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to workaround my problem. To answer my general question how to find out more about the package:

Instead of 'which' I used the ? command to explore the metadata of the class I knew of in the package. From that class I extracted the metadata of the package, found all the classes of the package, picked to appropriate one, found a list of all the methods of the class and also found the appropriate one. That is not really user friendly but it worked.

```
meta_group = ?slmetric.dashboard.Group
meta_package = meta_group.ContainingPackage

meta_classes = meta_package.ClassList
for i=1:7
    disp(meta_classes(i).Name)
end

meta_widget = meta_classes(5)
widget_methods = meta_widget.MethodList
for i=1:38
    disp(widget_methods(i).Name)
end
```

For my specific question: I used setWidthInt instead, which does not rely on using the Width enum, which I still did not find. I looked for the enum in

```
meta_classes.EnumerationMemberList
```

But that was empty for all classes in the package.